# Parse.com PHP setup

Tags: php, parse-platform

I am creating a web app using parse.com php sdk. I had created a login form and using AJAX to call the parse.com php login function

```
    try {
         $user = ParseUser::logIn("myname", "mypass");
         // Do stuff after successful login.
    } catch (ParseException $error) {
         // The login failed. Check error to see why.
    }
```

when I pass the wrong username and password, It returns the following warning.

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(https://api.parse.com/1/login?username=suresh%40inovawe.com&password=password123):
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in
>   /MyPath/vendor/parse/php-sdk/src/Parse/ParseClient.php
>   on line 240
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /MyPath/vendor/parse/php-sdk/src/Parse/ParseObject.php
>   on line 488
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /MyPath/vendor/parse/php-sdk/src/Parse/ParseObject.php
>   on line 528

And If I pass the correct username and password it returns nothing and in my index.php i have a condition to check user logged in

```
$currentUser = ParseUser::getCurrentUser();

if ($currentUser) {
    // do stuff with the user
    echo 'user loggedin';
} else {
    include "login.php";
}
```

it always executes the false block. Can anyone help me to solve it. It will be good if I get a nice tutorials for parse.com php.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after modifying my ParseClient.php file. Try reinstalling Parse PHP and it should work.

If you look in your ParseClient.php file at line 240 it will have  file_get_contents[snip].

If you look in Parse's ParseClient.php file it doesn't have this.